# Garlic brown spots, safe to eat the rest of the bulb?

Tags: garlic

[image]

The spots are bruises that bacteria have infected right? There is a slight discolouration into the "meat" of the garlic. Ok to eat the rest? With a bit of discolouration? Without?

If there were mold visible, should i have thrown the whole ting then? And if it were a cloved garlic, should i judge the cloves individually or the bulb as a whole?

Edit: Similar question to [Raised brown spots on garlic](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56673/raised-brown-spots-on-garlic) but they dont ask there if u can/should eat the rest of the bulb or clove.

Comment: Similar to [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56673/raised-brown-spots-on-garlic) question, although the spots may be different.  Personally, I just cut the spots off and use the rest.  One of the other answers does reference a source for doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can eat it. It is the same as a potato. You get brown spots on your potato you just cut the brown out. This is the same for garlic. If it is molded I would through it all out. I have eaten garlic and potatoes that have had brown spots for years. I'm still alive and kicking. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Personal answer, please do not take as in any way authoritative or backing safety:  I cut them off and use as long as not moldy.  I personally have allergies that I won't risk mold spores, but know others who even some mold does not stop them.  I find that a small amount cut off of otherwise sound cloves often results in a stronger flavor, but I personally like a strong garlic flavor.  Fortunately, so does rest of the house, to garlic breath is fair game.  If the garlic has also started to sprout, then I get a bitter flavor, so I may be a bit more prone to discard.

Garlic is often listed as a possible source of botulism, but these cautions are normally in regards to preserved garlic, especially in oil which provided the air free environment botulism needs.  Fresh garlic, it would seem would not be such a concern, but I do not have authoritative sources to back that opinion.